# Avoiding reordering of panels and toolbars in new QGIS project

Tags: qgis, gui, toolbar, qgis-customization

I can't find anything suiting the simple need of making a personal default ordering and look of toolbar items and panels.

I've saved a default project, but my toolbars are not in the same ordering as how I had them when saving the project. Then, for instance the "annotation panel" always shows, but I don't want to show it by default.

I know that there is the GUI customization and that I can uncheck the annotaion dock. But at a new session the panel is there again. And there's seemingly no way for keeping my desired layout and ordering of toolbars, docks/panels.

- QGIS version 3.12.3-București
- QGIS code revision 8234261527
- Compiled against Qt 5.11.2
- Running against Qt 5.11.2
- OS Version Windows 10 (10.0)

Comment: What system are you using?

Comment: @IanTurton, sorry - updated the OP with that info..

Comment: Did you try user profiles? https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html?#working-with-user-profiles

Comment: @babel from my understanding, everything I change in my GUI is actually saved in the current (default) user profile.